# How to nest shortcodes with Hugo ? raw HTML ommitted

Tags: syntax, nested, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I get into troubles with shortcodes in hugo.

1. To make some text-align:right I made an Align shortcode.
2. To add some color to the text I made a Color shortcode.
3. To wrap some content into a cream panel I have a Hint shortcode.

1 2 3 works well separately, but when I'm in a config where some text inside a cream panel needs to be on the right or in color I can't achieve that. By looking the html rendered source I see <--- raw HTML ommitted --->

document.md :

```
{{< hint cream >}}
Lorem {{< color red >}}ipsum{{< /color >}} example.
{{< align right >}}John Doe{{< /align >}}
{{< /hint >}}
```

Hint shortcode :

```
<blockquote class="hint {{ .Get 0 }}">
  {{ .Inner | markdownify }}
</blockquote>
```

Align shortcode :

```
<p style="text-align:{{.Get 0}}">{{ .Inner }}</p>
```

Color shortcode :

```
<span style="color:{{.Get 0}}">{{ .Inner | markdownify }}</span>
```

It should results in :

```
<blockquote class="hint cream">
<p>Lorem <span style="color:red">ipsum</span> example.
<p style="text-align:right">John Doe</p>
</blockquote>
```

But results in:

```
<blockquote class="hint cream">
<p>Lorem <--- raw HTML ommitted --->ipsum<--- raw HTML ommitted ---> example.
<--- raw HTML ommitted --->
</blockquote>
```

Someone can explain me what is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 4):

I just finally find it out.
If someone needs the answer, in the config.toml file of the site, add

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
unsafe= true
```

Then it will work.